# Org mode: Enable line numbers only in source code blocks

Tags: org-mode, line-numbers

Is there a way to enable line numbers only for the source code blocks between `#+BEGIN_SRC` and `#+END_SRC`?

Comment: There is no built-in support for such a feature.  The line numbers that are built-in get generated during redisplay by the C internals.  Prior to that implementation, there were a couple of libraries that generated line numbers with lisp ... but the feature was slower in long buffers due to `line-number-at-pos`.  It is possible to modify the `linum.el` library or `nlinum.el` to create the feature of line numbers for source code blocks, but that would be a nontrivial undertaking.  Attempts to limit line numbers in Lisp to only the visible windows is also nontrivial, and not 100% accurate.

Comment: To the extent the O.P. is interested in displaying line numbers on the output / export of evaluated src code blocks, see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170382/org-mode-source-inclusion-line-numbers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to have it only display in Babel blocks, but I can suggest how to get line numbers displaying only when you're inside a Babel block.

You can turn on line-num mode if you're in a Babel block with:

```
(if (org-in-src-block-p) ...
```

And continuously check if you're in a Babel block by running `(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'my/line-num-babel)`.

Finally, you can take some hints here to change where line number 1 is located: [Zero-indexed line numbering](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20008/zero-indexed-line-numbering). In fact, the second answer there with the comment `Update line numbers for the portion visible in window WIN.` may be able useful for only showing line numbers in Babel blocks.

In summary, this is Emacs, so you can absolutely do what you want. But it might not exist. If you write it and release it as a package, I assume others would be interested in using this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite old. But for the sake of someone else could get it.
Plus I use doom emacs. So maybe something could be different.

The code just showing a way to get linenumber display besides code-block, and the line number would change on your edit, and current line would highlighted.
The main idea is modifing some org-indent line-prefix and wrap-prefix to add a line number. So org-indent should be enabled to get this work done.
For I didn't want all the buffer lines to be calculated after every edit work, sone local variable defined to narrow the range to the current code block. Other local variable defined to allow setting up the action.
Furthor more, on occuping the highlight current line overlay to highlight the current line.

```
(defvar show-code-block-linum t
  " line number of code block ")

(setq show-code-block-linum t)

(defface org-block-show-num
  '((default :inherit org-block)
    (((class color) (min-colors 256) (background light))
     :foreground "grey75" :slant italic)
    (((class color) (min-colors 256) (background dark))
     :foreground "#3F3A58" :slant italic)
    (((class color) (min-colors 8))
     :foreground "black" :slant italic))
  "face used in org-src-code linenumber"
  :group 'org-faces)

(defvar-local org-src-block-linum 0
  " line number of code block ")
(defvar-local org-src-block-line-cnt 0
  " line count of code block ")
(defvar-local org-src-block-inside-block-p nil
  " if curline is in code block ")
(defvar-local org-src-block-linum-width 0
  " line number width in src block ")
(defvar-local org-src-block-line-num-fmt ""
  " line number format in src block ")
;; (defvar org-src-block-line-num-sep (org-add-props " ▏" nil 'face '(org-block org-hide))
(defvar org-src-block-line-num-sep " ▏"
  " line number seprator of src block ")
(setq org-src-block-line-num-sep " ")
(defun myfunc/org-indent-set-line-properties (level indentation &optional heading)
  "Set prefix properties on current line an move to next one.

LEVEL is the current level of heading.  INDENTATION is the
expected indentation when wrapping line.

When optional argument HEADING is non-nil, assume line is at
a heading.  Moreover, if it is `inlinetask', the first star will
have `org-warning' face."
  (let* ((case-fold-search t)
         (line (aref (pcase heading
               (`nil org-indent--text-line-prefixes)
               (`inlinetask org-indent--inlinetask-line-prefixes)
               (_ org-indent--heading-line-prefixes))
             level))
         (wrap line)
         bg ed)
    ;; (beginning-of-line)
    (when (and show-code-block-linum
               (looking-at-p "^[ \t]*#\\+BEGIN_SRC[ \t]"))
      (setq bg (point))
      (org-with-wide-buffer
       (when (re-search-forward "^[ \t]*#\\+END_SRC[ \t]*$" nil t)
         (setq ed (point))
         (setq org-src-block-inside-block-p t)
         (setq org-src-block-linum 0)
         (setq org-src-block-line-cnt (- (count-lines bg ed) 2))
         ;; (message (format "%d - %d : %d" (line-number-at-pos bg) (line-number-at-pos ed) org-src-block-line-cnt))
         (setq org-src-block-linum-width (string-width (number-to-string org-src-block-line-cnt)))
         (setq org-src-block-line-num-fmt (format "%%%dd%%s" org-src-block-linum-width))
         (goto-char bg))))
    (when org-src-block-inside-block-p
         (when (> org-src-block-linum 0)
           (setq wrap (concat
                       wrap
                       (org-add-props
                           (concat
                            (make-string org-src-block-linum-width ?\s)
                            org-src-block-line-num-sep)
                           nil 'face 'org-block-show-num)))
           (setq line (concat
                       line
                       (org-add-props
                           (format org-src-block-line-num-fmt org-src-block-linum
                                   org-src-block-line-num-sep)
                           nil 'face 'org-block-show-num))))
         (cl-incf org-src-block-linum)
         (when (> org-src-block-linum org-src-block-line-cnt)
           ;; (message (format "stopped at line %d" (line-number-at-pos)))
           (setq org-src-block-inside-block-p nil)))
    (setq wrap
          (concat wrap
                  (org-add-props
                      (if heading (concat (make-string level ?*) " ")
                        (make-string indentation ?\s))
                      nil 'face (if org-src-block-inside-block-p
                                    'org-block-show-num
                                  'org-indent))))
    ;; Add properties down to the next line to indent empty lines.
    (add-text-properties (line-beginning-position) (line-beginning-position 2)
             `(line-prefix ,line wrap-prefix ,wrap)))
  (forward-line))
(advice-add 'org-indent-set-line-properties :override #'myfunc/org-indent-set-line-properties)
(defun myfunc/org-indent-refresh-maybe (beg end _)
  "Refresh indentation properties in an adequate portion of buffer.
BEG and END are the positions of the beginning and end of the
range of inserted text.  DUMMY is an unused argument.

This function is meant to be called by `after-change-functions'."
  (when org-indent-mode
    (save-match-data
      ;; If a headline was modified or inserted, set properties until
      ;; next headline.
      (org-with-wide-buffer
       (if (or org-indent-modified-headline-flag
           (save-excursion
         (goto-char beg)
         (forward-line 0)
         (re-search-forward
          (org-with-limited-levels org-outline-regexp-bol)
                  (save-excursion
                    (goto-char end)
                    ;; Extend to headline if END is within its
                    ;; headline stars.
                    (line-end-position))
                  t)))
       (let ((end (save-excursion
            (goto-char end)
            (org-with-limited-levels (outline-next-heading))
            (point))))
         (setq org-indent-modified-headline-flag nil)
         (org-indent-add-properties beg end))
     ;; Otherwise, only set properties on modified area.
         (if (and show-code-block-linum
                  (eq 'src-block (org-element-type (org-element-at-point))))
             (let ((element (org-element-at-point)))
               (org-indent-add-properties (org-element-begin element) (org-element-end element)))
           (org-indent-add-properties beg end)))))))
(advice-add 'org-indent-refresh-maybe :override #'myfunc/org-indent-refresh-maybe)

;; From Here, functions for highlight current line-number
  (defun text-property-face-replace (text face-replace-alist)
    "Replace faces in TEXT using FACE-REPLACE-ALIST."
    (let ((pos-beg 0)
          (pos-end (length text))
          (ret nil))
      (while (< pos-beg pos-end)
        (let ((text-props (text-properties-at pos-beg text)))
          (let ((prop-iter (memq 'face text-props)))
            (when prop-iter
              (let ((value-src (car (cdr prop-iter))))
                (let ((value-dst
                       (cond
                        ((listp value-src)
                         nil) ;; TODO: support `plists' and other complex cases.
                        (t
                         (assq value-src face-replace-alist)))))
                  (when value-dst
                    (setq ret t)
                    (setcdr prop-iter (cons (cdr value-dst) (cdr (cdr prop-iter))))))))))
        (setq pos-beg (next-property-change pos-beg text pos-end)))
      (if ret text nil)))

  (defun modify-org-src-block-curline-overlay ()
    (let ((line (concat (get-text-property (point) 'line-prefix)))
          (wrap (concat (get-text-property (point) 'wrap-prefix)))
          (face-alist '((org-block-show-num . line-number-current-line))))
      (when (and show-code-block-linum (overlayp hl-line-overlay))
        (overlay-put hl-line-overlay 'line-prefix
                     (text-property-face-replace line face-alist))
        (overlay-put hl-line-overlay 'wrap-prefix
                     (text-property-face-replace wrap face-alist)))))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook #'modify-org-src-block-curline-overlay nil t)
```

Comment: Please add to your answer an explanation of the code, saying how it answers the question. Thx.

Comment: The code above just showing a way to get linenumber display besides code-block, and the line number would change on your edit, and current line would highlighted.
The main idea is modifing some org-indent line-prefix and wrap-prefix to add a line number. So org-indent should be enabled to get this work done.
For I didn't want all the buffer lines to be calculated after every edit work, sone local variable defined to narrow the range to the current code block.
Furthor more, on occuping the highlight current line overlay to highlight the current line.

Comment: For I'm not familliar with lisp, any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Please put all explanatory info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time, and they're not searchable. Thx.

Comment: OK. I've update my answers.